# Sails.js: Page specific .less files

Tags: node.js, less, gruntjs, sails.js

I have a "page specific" .less file in my project that I need to reference in a particular view. For this reason I cannot add it to the `importer.less`

I am having hard time making this work.

For example, I am adding this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/homepage.css">` directly to my `homepage.ejs`, but browser returns 404 not found since my `homepage.less` is not being compiled and copied over to the `.tmp` directory.

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: Did you look up in your Gruntfile.js ? Did you put the .less in the referenced src ?

Answer (score 2):

1. create a `assets/styles/home.less` file with your home specific styles. Notice that this file can @import "importer.less" to reuse your default styles
2. than add the home.less into the less task in the `tasks/config/less.js` as follows:

   ```
   grunt.config.set('less', {
           dev: {
                   files: [{
                           expand: true,
                           cwd: 'assets/styles/',
                           src: ['importer.less','home.less'],
                           dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
                           ext: '.css'
                   }]
           }
   });
   ```
3. Now you should be able to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/homepage.css">`